# Angular Event throws error in ViewChild decorator component

Tags: angular

I have a Child Component `child.component.ts` with function

```
RenderData(test:false, event:Event) {
if(test) {
event.stopPropagation();
}
....
}
```

on another component where I am trying to import this function I have a child decorator

```
Test.Component.ts

@ViewChild('plainComponent')
plainComponent: PlainComponent;

// here I am trying to import RenderData();

openBox(dialog:MatDialogRef<any>) {
this.plainComponent.RenderData(false, Event);

}
```

Test.Component.html

```
<app-plain #plainComponent></app-plain>
      <div>
        <button mat-raised-button color="primary" (click)="done(dialog)">Run</button>
```

This EVENT there throws an error:

> error TS2345: Argument of type '{ new (type: string, eventInitDict?:
> EventInit): Event; prototype: Event; readonly AT_TARGET: number;
> readonly BUBBLING_PHASE: number; readonly CAPTURING_PHASE: number;
> readonly NONE: number; }' is not assignable to parameter of type
> 'Event'.

How do I solve this Event error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should intialise Event class

```
openBox(dialog:MatDialogRef<any>) {
      this.plainComponent.RenderData(false, new Event('click');
}
```